# Display number of specific images in div

Tags: javascript

What I would like is to count the number of src containing the name empty.jpg inside a div using javascript.
Here is a sample of the code:

```
<div id="up-bil">
<input name="billed" type="checkbox" value="" />
<img src="Lighthouse.jpg"/>
<input name="billed" type="checkbox" value="" />
<img src="Lighthouse.jpg" />
<input name="billed" type="checkbox" value="" />
<img src="images.jpg" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var b = document.getElementById("up-bil").getElementsByTagName("img");
   b.getAttribute("src")=="empty.jpg";
   alert(b.length);
</script>
```

Nothing happens with this code.
Can someone give me a clue what to do?

Comment: Initialize a variable count as 0. And check `if(b.getAttribute("src")=="empty.jpg";){ increment count }`. Put it in a loop

Comment: b is an array... so, it doesn't have that function.

Answer (score 5):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a collection, so you'd have to iterate, and check each element, then increment a counter:

```
var elems = document.getElementById("up-bil").getElementsByTagName("img");
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].src == "empty.jpg") count++;
}
console.log(count);
```

If you have access to `document.querySelectorAll` you can do:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#up-bill img[src='empty.jpg']");
console.log(elems.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgs = document.getElementById("up-bil").getElementsByTagName('img');
var howMany = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
 var currentSrc = imgs[i].getAttribute('src');
 if(currentSrc.indexOf("empty.jpg")>0)howMany++; 
}
console.log(howMany);
```

This checks the whole src for `empty.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You have two main problems here:

1. `getElementsByTagName()` will return a collection and you have to iterate it.
2. `b.getAttribute("src")=="empty.jpg";` will not do anything, you are not testing anything here.

Your code should be like this:

```
var counter = 0;
for (var img in document.getElementById("up-bil").getElementsByTagName('img')) {
    if (img.src === "empty.jpg") counter++; // use === to compare and to assure value and type equality.
}
```